# how to fill combobox in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

**I tried and this is my attempt Please help me**
i need to fill combobox in jsp from my database

1-jsp page

```
       <p class="ppp">Category</p>
<jsp:useBean id="categorys" class="database.conDB" scope="page"/>
<select name="categorys" size="1" style="width:196px; padding:5px;" >
<c:forEach var="categ" items="${categorys.categoryNames} ">
 <option value="${categ}">${categ} </option>
 </c:forEach>  
</select>
```

===========
2-this my function in conDB class

```
    public String[] getCategory()
{
    String query="SELECT category_name FROM books.category;";
    Statement statement;
    ResultSet resultSet ;
    try{
        statement=createConnection().createStatement();
        resultSet=statement.executeQuery(query);
        int count=0;
        while(resultSet.next())
                count++;
        categoryNames=new String[count];
        resultSet.first();
        do{
            categoryNames[count -1]=resultSet.getString("category_name");
            count--;

        }while(resultSet.next());


    }catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    for (int i = categoryNames.length; i > 0; i--)
        System.out.println(categoryNames[i - 1]);
    return categoryNames;
    }
```

Comment: You need to add select tagd and just a hint: remember to close resultSet!

Comment: thanx @ Alireza Fattahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `selected` attribute to the `<option>` tag you want to select.

For example:

```
<option value="${categ}" ${ <<selected condition>> ? 'selected' : ''>${categ}</option>
```

`<<selected condition>>` is the condition that is used to determine if the category should be selected. E.g. If you want to always select the category named `house` it would be: `categ == 'house'`

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i run my code

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /search.jsp(176,0) '${categorys.categoryNames}' Property 'categoryNames' not found on type database.conDB

Comment: I don't think that this has something to do with my answer. If the property `categoryNames` cannot be found something else is broken in your code.