# how to display "Model object Attribute ArrayList<String>" values as DROP DOWN values in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, arraylist

```
<form:form action="saveNewUsers" method="post" modelAttribute="users">
        <table>
        <tr><td>Id</td>
                <td><form:input path="id"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User</td>
                <td><form:input path="user" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FirstName</td>
                <td><form:input path="first_name" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>LastName</td>
                <td><form:input path="last_name" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Group Id</td>
            <td>
               <select name="GroupId">
                 <c:forEach items="${users.al}" var="item">
                   <option value="${item.value}">${item.value}</option>
                 </c:forEach>
                </select>
             </td>

             <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>

     </table>
```

Please let me know how to get ArrayList attribute from ModelObject of 'users' and print those values of ArrayList as DROPDOWN Menu in JSP.
Actually I send that 'users' model object from the Controller of the Spring MVC

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895159/how-to-fill-combobox-in-jsp

Comment: Very  thank you JMCG sir. I thought your answer is not suitable to me. But after I finally achieved my task from some where else, that code is also similar to JMCG referred code. Once again thank you JMCG.......:)